# How to Output Results to HTML file in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am newbie to `R Markdown`. I am using `R Studio` and am very comfortable with it. I have some R code in an `R Markdown` file that I am using in `R Studio`. The code reads a `.csv` file of streamflow data and calculates the mean flow. I want to export the resulting mean flow to `HTML`, which is done when I hit the Knit icon. But all I see in the last line of the HTML file is "mean_flow", and the actual numeric value is missing. I understand I need to do this using r in inline mode, which I tried to do using the following r code excerpt:

```
    mean_flow<-mean(daily_flow$Value,na.rm=T)
    max_flow<-max(daily_flow$Value,na.rm=T)
    min_flow<-min(daily_flow$Value,na.rm=T)
    sd_flow<-sd(daily_flow$Value,na.rm=T)
    CV_flow<-(sd_flow/mean_flow)*100
    mean_flow `r print(mean_flow)
```

Note: all except " mean_flow `r print(mean_flow)` " is in one code chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mean_flow `r mean_flow`
```

Also, we can use `format` to change the format:

```
mean_flow `r format(mean_flow, digits = 1, nsmall = 1)`
```